# setattr if hasattr else setattr on self.item

Tags: python

Task: `setattr(self, key, value) if hasattr(self, key) else setattr(otherobject, key, value)` where `otherobject` is an attribute of `self`

The problem has two problems that I am unable to solve.

1. `setattr(self.baz, key, value)` ends badly if `__setattr__` is re-defined, because you cannot assign `self.baz` without calling `__setattr__` which requires `self.baz` to be defined.
2. I want the behavior of `__getattr__` (called when the default attribute access fails) in my `__setattr__` (called when an attribute assignment is attempted) where it is only called when hasattr(self, key) is False.

The below code is wrong; I expect that the solution will resemble...

```
def monkeypatchsetattr(obj, oldsetattr):
    def newsetattr(key, value):
        # hasattr(self, key) will return true if key is an attrib of baz
        # and so is not a good test
        if key is self.__dict__:
            oldsetattr(key, value)
        else:
            setattr(obj.baz, key, value)

    return newsetattr

class Baz():
    pass

class Qux():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.color = 'red'
        self.baz = Baz()
        self.__setattr__ = monkeypatchedselfattr(self, self.__setattr__)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.baz, item)

    def __setattr__(self, item, value):
        if hasattr(self, item):
            super(Qux, self).__setattr__(self, item, value)
        else:
            setattr(self.baz, item, value)
```

Problem 1 is the bigger and more immediate problem.

Is there a more elegant solution to Problem 2 after Problem 1 is resolved?

Comment: Surely `Baz` has more going on than just `pass`?

Comment: Yes. I've omitted all the code that seemed extraneous to wanting to set the attribute. `Baz` is a core object. `Qux` is a wrapper for `Baz`. An instance of `Baz` can be referenced by multiple `Qux` instances.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that something in the `Baz.__getattr__` seems like it's probably circular if it's causing the maximum recursion depth.

Comment: Can you include the `__getattr__` for Baz?

Comment: I ran the code exactly as posted in the question.